# BOT Framework - Unable to Connect Luis- AI Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Below are the source Code for communicating to LUIS- AI from my Bot application. When I try to communicate I am always getting Access Denied response. I don't know what I am missing here.

```
 [LuisModel("8c9285fb-198a-4f49-8fe4-b08ac5541ac2", "5c47c63887e346c2aee24d1755e07d29")]
    [Serializable]
    public class LUISDialog:LuisDialog<RoomReservation>
    {
        private readonly BuildFormDelegate<RoomReservation> Reservation;

        public LUISDialog(BuildFormDelegate<RoomReservation> reservceRoom)
        {
            this.Reservation = reservceRoom;
        }
        [LuisIntent("")]
        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext dialogContext, LuisResult luisResult)
        {
            await dialogContext.PostAsync("I am sorry I don't know what you mean ");
            dialogContext.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Greeting")]
        public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext dialogContext, LuisResult luisResult)
        {
         dialogContext.Call(new GreetingDialog(), CallBack);
        }

        private async Task CallBack(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Reservation")]
        public async Task RoomReservation(IDialogContext dialogContext, LuisResult luisResult)
        {
            FormDialog<RoomReservation> enrollmentForm =new FormDialog<RoomReservation>(new RoomReservation(),this.Reservation, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
            dialogContext.Call(enrollmentForm, CallBack);
        }

        [LuisIntent("QueryAmenities")]
        public async Task QueryAmenities(IDialogContext dialogContext, LuisResult luisResult)
        {
            foreach (var entity in luisResult.Entities.Where(entity=>entity.Type=="Amenity"))
            {
                var value = entity.Entity.ToLower();
                if (value == "pool" || value == "gym" || value == "wifi" || value == "towels")
                {
                    await dialogContext.PostAsync("Yes we have that");
                    dialogContext.Wait(MessageReceived);
                    return;
                }
                await dialogContext.PostAsync("I'am sorry we don't have that");
                dialogContext.Wait(MessageReceived);
                return;
            }
            await dialogContext.PostAsync("I'am sorry we don't have that");
            dialogContext.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
    }
```

**Screen shot of error I am getting**
[image]

**Controller Code**

```
[BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                //// calculate something for us to return
                //int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

                //// return our reply to the user
                //Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
                //await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                // await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>  HotelBotDialog.dialog);
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeLuisDialog);
            }
            else
            {
                 await HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
```

**LUIS Intent**

[image]

Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

I just tested a connection to your LUIS and it seems to be working: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/8c9285fb-198a-4f49-8fe4-b08ac5541ac2?subscription-key=5c47c63887e346c2aee24d1755e07d29&verbose=true&q=hello

Comment: If the direct call does it work then I suggest to call LUIS by a method rather than adding  [LuisIntent("***")] at the top. It is even easier if you want to implement more cognitive APIs in the future

Comment: Also, I always call the dialogs like this: await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, ()=> new MakeLuisDialog()); instead of await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeLuisDialog);

Comment: i don't know in my case what going wrong from the bot application. Is there any way to trouble shoot LUIS?

Comment: but LUIS is not failing, click the link, it is your own LUIS app! https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/8c9285fb-198a-4f49-8fe4-b08ac5541ac2?subscription-key=5c47c63887e346c2aee24d1755e07d29&verbose=true&q=hello

Comment: If you like I can help you right know via teamviewer, add me on skype: fercomreal1

Comment: I don't think it's Source code pblm. LUIS framework showing weird. Today I have tried and it's working without changing the source code. It's strange. Also they have changed their entire portal on today.

Comment: Well, maybe you just ran out of the uses of the month (if you are on a free plan)

Answer (score 0):

Probrably you are using the endpoint key instead the Programmatic Key API. Check this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6K4W.png)